# Elasticsearch one specific shard keep initializing in different data nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, sharding, elk

I am getting ElasticsearchStatusWarning saying that the cluster state is yellow. Upon running the health check API, I see below

> curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health/

```
{"cluster_name":"my-elasticsearch","status":"yellow","timed_out":false,"number_of_nodes":8,"number_of_data_nodes":3,"active_primary_shards":220,"active_shards":438,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":2,"unassigned_shards":0,"delayed_unassigned_shards":0,"number_of_pending_tasks":0,"number_of_in_flight_fetch":0,"task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis":0,"active_shards_percent_as_number":99.54545454545455}
```

initializing_shards is 2. So, I further run the below call

> curl -X GET
> http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards?h=index,shard,prirep,state,unassigned.reason
> |grep INIT

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 33457  100 33457    0   graph_vertex_24_18549             0 r INITIALIZING ALLOCATION_FAILED
  0  79609      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 79659
```

> curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards/graph_vertex_24_18549

```
graph_vertex_24_18549 0 p STARTED      8373375 8.4gb IP1   elasticsearch-data-1
graph_vertex_24_18549 0 r INITIALIZING               IP2 elasticsearch-data-2
```

And rerunning the same command in few mins, shows now it's being initialized in elasticsearch-data-0. See below

```
graph_vertex_24_18549 0 p STARTED      8373375 8.4gb IP1   elasticsearch-data-1
graph_vertex_24_18549 0 r INITIALIZING               IP0   elasticsearch-data-0
```

If i rerun it again in few mins, I can see it's again being initialized in elasticsearch-data-2 again. But it never gets STARTED.

> curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/_cat/allocation?v

```
shards disk.indices disk.used disk.avail disk.total disk.percent host          ip            node
   147      162.2gb   183.8gb    308.1gb      492gb           37 IP1 IP1 elasticsearch-data-2
   146      217.3gb   234.2gb    257.7gb      492gb           47 IP2   IP2   elasticsearch-data-1
   147      216.6gb   231.2gb    260.7gb      492gb           47 IP3  IP3  elasticsearch-data-0
```

> curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v

```
ip            heap.percent ram.percent cpu load_1m load_5m load_15m node.role master name
IP1            7          77  20    4.17    4.57     4.88 mi        -      elasticsearch-master-2
IP2          72          59   7    2.59    2.38     2.19 i         -      elasticsearch-5f4bd5b88f-4lvxz
IP3           57          49   3    0.75    1.13     1.09 di        -      elasticsearch-data-2
IP4           63          57  21    2.69    3.58     4.11 di        -      elasticsearch-data-0
IP5            5          59   7    2.59    2.38     2.19 mi        -      elasticsearch-master-0
IP6            69          53  13    4.67    4.60     4.66 di        -      elasticsearch-data-1
IP7           8          70  14    2.86    3.20     3.09 mi        *      elasticsearch-master-1
IP8           30          77  20    4.17    4.57     4.88 i         -      elasticsearch-5f4bd5b88f-wnrl4
```

> curl -s -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cluster/allocation/explain -d '{
> "index": "graph_vertex_24_18549",   "shard":
> 0,   "primary": false }' -H 'Content-type: application/json'

```
{"index":"graph_vertex_24_18549","shard":0,"primary":false,"current_state":"initializing","unassigned_info":{"reason":"ALLOCATION_FAILED","at":"2020-11-04T08:21:45.756Z","failed_allocation_attempts":1,"details":"failed shard on node [1XEXS92jTK-wwanNgQrxsA]: failed to perform indices:data/write/bulk[s] on replica [graph_vertex_24_18549][0], node[1XEXS92jTK-wwanNgQrxsA], [R], s[STARTED], a[id=RnTOlfQuQkOumVuw_NeuTw], failure RemoteTransportException[[elasticsearch-data-2][IP:9300][indices:data/write/bulk[s][r]]]; nested: CircuitBreakingException[[parent] Data too large, data for [<transport_request>] would be [4322682690/4gb], which is larger than the limit of [4005632409/3.7gb], real usage: [3646987112/3.3gb], new bytes reserved: [675695578/644.3mb]]; ","last_allocation_status":"no_attempt"},"current_node":{"id":"o_9jyrmOSca9T12J4bY0Nw","name":"elasticsearch-data-0","transport_address":"IP:9300"},"explanation":"the shard is in the process of initializing on node [elasticsearch-data-0], wait until initialization has completed"}
```

Thing is I was earlier getting alerted for Unassigned Shards due to the same exception as above - "CircuitBreakingException[[parent] Data too large, data for [<transport_request>] would be [4322682690/4gb], which is larger than the limit of [4005632409/3.7gb]"

But back then heap was only 2G. I increased it to 4G. And now I am seeing same error, but this time with respect to Initialising shards instead of Unallocated shards.

How can I remediate this?

Comment: Can you provide the output you get from `GET _cat/allocation?v` and `GET _cat/nodes?v` ?

Comment: @Val Sure. Adding it in question due to formatting issues in comment.

Comment: Please update your question instead, it's not legible in comments

Comment: @Val Done. I have updated the question now.

Comment: Thanks, one more please: `curl -s -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cluster/allocation/explain -d '{
  "index": "graph_vertex_24_18549",
  "shard": 0,
  "primary": false
}'`

Comment: Not able to execute it. Getting {"error":"Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported","status":406} @Val

Comment: Sorry, add `-H 'Content-type: application/json'` on the command-line

Comment: @Val Adding it in question once again. Still it's initializing

Comment: Can you add the response you get please?

Comment: I've added now. Weird thing is for some time, it listed the shard as STARTED. But has now gone back to INITIALISING @Val

Comment: As you can see you probably need to further increase the resources or figure out what is causing this data overload and reduce it.